# I can't navigate to state ui router from address bar

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-click

I have a problem navigating to a state from the address bar or when i refresh the current state.
 i have the following code:

Controller:

```
$scope.selectCategory = function(category) {    
$location.path('/posts/' +category.category);
$scope.posts=[];
Post.query({category: category.id}).$promise.then(function(posts){
  $scope.category = $stateParams.category;
  $scope.posts = posts;
  $scope.sortBy = "-updated";
  $scope.letterLimit = 100;
  $scope.postDisplayed = 6;

  function setCurrentPost(post) {
    $scope.currentPost = post;
  }
  $scope.setCurrentPost = setCurrentPost;


});
```

}

so in the code above i'm binding my posts to scope category, when a user click a particular category, he will be directed to a page which render the posts of that specific category.

I'm calling the url in state router as follows:

app.js:

```
.state('posts.category', {
    url: '/:category',
    templateUrl: 'static/partials/post/postlist.html',
  })
```

then the user has to click a specific category to be directed to that url. I used ng-click to achieve that in my html:

```
<img ng-click="selectCategory(category)" ng-src="[[category.image]]" err-src="../../../static/img/imageholder.png" alt="img01"/>
```

I'm using Resource query to call posts from api as follows.

services:

```
.factory('Post', ['$resource', function($resource){
return $resource('/api/posts/:category', {category:'@category'});
}])
```

finally in the page rendering the posts, i'm using ng-repeat to loop through the posts as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts | limitTo:postDisplayed | filter: searchText | orderBy: sortBy" >
```

So far evrything works fine. When the user clicks a specific category it is directed to the correct page and posts are rendered.

My problem if the user refresh the page or try to access the page by entering url in the address bar, or i sent the url link to someone and clicks on it, the page rendered is blank, which means the scope function selectCategory is not called at all. In other words my function selectCategory is only called through ng-click, otherwise is not called at all through state router. Any idea how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please show the code of `selectCategory` method and provide information if that method is called from parent state controller( parent state may be `posts`)?

Comment: @ ex0dm3nt  thanks for your reply. Below is the information of parent state:
.state('posts', {
        url: '/posts',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'static/partials/post/mainpost.html',
      })
 code for selectCategory is mentioned above in controller section. Let me know if anything else is needed. thanks

Comment: do you have a separate controller for `posts.category` state? how are you displaying data in the template? By using that controller where the `selectCategory` method is declared?

Comment: Well i'm using the ng resource to call api and exract data from there, i used services for that as mentioned above, one the user clicks on ng-click in the template, http call to my api is made and the list of posts is rendered, and i loop through that list using ng-repeat.
I don't have a seperate controller for posts.category. selectCategory controller is used to make the http call.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your code, you don't have code that is responsible for loading category data when the URL in question is accessed directly.

For the sake of keeping things separate and not complicate your code you should really add a controller for your `posts.category` state. Modify your state like this:

```
.state('posts.category', {
    url: '/:category',
    templateUrl: 'static/partials/post/postlist.html',
    controller: 'PostsCategoryController'
  })
```

Then, create a `PostsCategoryController` which will be used for your `posts.category` state. Something like this

```
yourModule.controller('PostsCategoryController', PostsCategoryController);

PostsCategoryController.$inject = ['$scope', '$stateParams']; //add additional dependencies you need.

function PostsCategoryController($scope, $stateParams){
  //code for handling posts category data and initialization
}
```

Then, load and initialize data in your `PostsCategoryController`. You can do that by taking the code from `selectCategory` method and modify it a bit, like this:

```
function PostsCategoryController($scope, $stateParams){

     function selectAndInitializeCategory(){
          //your Post.query code for getting the data (you can use $stateParams to get category)
       }

      selectAndInitializeCategory();

    }
```

Please note that you will have to reference your `PostsCategoryController` in your `static/partials/post/postlist.html` template.

Comment: Sorry for not making myself clear. I do have a controller for category which render a list of categories. when user clicks on category is redirected to posts page.
this is the state for category: .state('/', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'static/partials/index.html',
        controller: 'CategoryCtrl',
      })
and resource for categories is as follows: .factory('Category', ['$resource', function($resource){
        return $resource('/api/categories:id/');
    }])
category controller : Category.query(function(response){
    $scope.categorys = response;   
  });

Comment: That is fine. What I have posted is a controller for `posts.category` state or your `/:category` URL. Basically, you want to have code that handles and displays data when you enter URL in address bar directly, and best place to handle that kind of code is a separate controller.

Comment: Ok  ex0dm3nt, i'll try that. Thanks a lot for your help!